# How do I change a class with three values to binary values in SAS?

Tags: binary, sas

I have a medical dataset that is a .csv file that I am cleaning and performing dimensionality reduction on. I have one class that is "Readmitted" and the possible outcomes are "No", ">30" for yes and the patient was readmitted in greater than 30 days, and "<30" for yes and the patient was readmitted in less than 30 days. I'd like to change these to binary for a logistic regression. I.e. I'd like for "<30" and ">30" to all become "1" and "No" to become "0". What is the programming necessary in SAS for this? I apologize for the rudimentary question. I'm very new with SAS.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the three values into 0 or 1 by assigning a variable the results of a logical evaluation (which is 1 for true and 0 for false)

```
readmitted_flag = readmit_value ne "No";
```

which is the same as

```
readmitted_flag = readmit_value in ('>30', '<30');
```

Another approach is to map the single three valued variable into 3 separate mutually exclusive binary flag variables

```
readmitted_none_flag = readmit_value eq "No";
readmitted_gt30_flag = readmit_value eq ">30";
readmitted_lt30_flag = readmit_value eq "<30";
```